# When we can equate two probability functions $p(r)dr=p(\gamma)d\gamma$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am doing wireless communication the signal envelope is assumed to have rayleigh fading given by $$p(r_i)= \frac{r_i}{\sigma^2} \exp\left(-\frac{r_i^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$ and we need to find distribution of SNR given by$$p(\gamma)|d(\gamma_i)|=p(r_i)|d(r_i)|   ~~~\text{and}~~~~ \gamma_i=\frac{r_i^2}{2N}\tag{1}$$

I want to know how equation one comes, I mean to say I have seen in coordinate geometry $\text{slope} = \frac{|\text{length of } y|}{|\text{length of }x|} $, but what specifically leads to (1).

Comment: And since they both have the same random variable 'r' so they are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is used here is the following result (see Theorem 1.1 in [this note](http://www.math.umd.edu/~millson/teaching/STAT400fall14/handouts/changeofvariable.pdf)):

> Suppose $X$ is continuous with probability density function $f_X(x)$. Let
>   $y = h(x)$ with $h$ a strictly increasing continuously differentiable function with inverse $x = g(y)$. Then $Y = h(X)$ is continuous with probability density function $f_Y(y)$ given by
>   $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g(y)) g'(y)$$